# Why is the size of my image from the drawable folder increasing?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to compare two screenshots. This is needed for autotesting.
One screenshot has been uploaded to the drawable folder (in Android Studio).
The other one I get when running autotests.
I've encountered a problem. I take out the screenshot from the drawable folder and it changes size. This happens in the method `loadBitmapFromDrawable()`

```
val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>().resources,
    R.drawable.main_screen,
    options
)
val expectedWidth = options.outWidth
val expectedHeight = options.outHeight
Log.i("LogJo", "I see that the real size of the screenshot is 1080 x 2220 ")

val expectedBitmap = loadBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.main_screen)
Log.i(
    "LogJo",
    "I see that the screenshot size is 2970 x 6105 ${expectedBitmap.width} x ${expectedBitmap.height}"
)
```

Here is the method, which for some reason changes the size of the screenshot:

```
private fun loadBitmapFromDrawable(drawableId: Int): Bitmap {
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options().apply {
        // Setting inJustDecodeBounds to true to extract dimensions without actually loading the bitmap
        inJustDecodeBounds = true
    }
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>().resources,
        drawableId,
        options
    )

    // Logs for checking sizes before and after loading
    Log.i(
        "ImageComparison",
        "Original bitmap dimensions: ${options.outWidth} x ${options.outHeight}"
    )

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>().resources,
        drawableId,
        options
    )

    // Logs for checking sizes after downloading
    Log.i("ImageComparison", "Loaded bitmap dimensions: ${bitmap.width} x ${bitmap.height}")

    return bitmap
}
```

Comment: Size or dimensions? From the code looks like the latter?

Comment: Dont put in drawable folder. Put it in assets.

Comment: Yes, this decision is correct. This is how I did it

Answer (score 0):

**Put it in assets**
This is how I did it

```
private fun loadBitmapFromAssets(fileName: String): Bitmap {
    val assetManager: AssetManager = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>().assets
    val inputStream: InputStream = assetManager.open(fileName)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
}
```